# Javascript Raphael to create and remove multiple text points

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have some code that prints text at specific points

```
group = paper.set();

for (var i = 0; i < numClicks; i++){
    group.push(paper.text(clicksX[i], clicksY[i], "TEST"));
}
```

That works great and the "TEST" shows up perfectly. However, I now want to remove all the "TEST" strings from my paper (to start again). How do I do this?

I've tried:

```
group.clear()

group.remove()

group.forEach(function(txt){txt.remove();})
```

and

```
group.forEach(function(txt){group.exclude(txt)})
```

but nothing seems to work. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: This line group.forEach(function(txt){txt.remove();}) works for me. Could you put your example on a jsfiddle so we can see whats happening.

Comment: Thanks Ian, you're right - I just had it in the wrong place in my code. Thanks so much for the sanity check!!

Answer (score 0):

group.forEach(function(txt){txt.remove();}) does work if it's in the right place in the script.

Thanks to Ian!